# Сдвиг левого блока на странице

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, есть страница, header, leftbloc, content, rightbloc, footer, ну вот я бы хотел сделать возможным скрывать по требованию ЛЕВЫЙ блок (leftbloc) при этом блок контента чтоб расширялся, чтоб не оставалось пустого места

Comment: В тэгах у вас написано "php" и "html". Вы хотите обойтись только этими средствами?

Comment: ну как бы да, но если я правильно понимаю то не обойтись без яваскриптов или jquery

Comment: Ну, так "на вскидку", то теоретически можно использовать или сессии, или печеньки. Т.е. после назатия на какую-нибудь кнопку "Скрыть", сохраняете в куки/сессии значение, по которому и будете ориентироваться: показывать данному пользователю сайдбар или нет. Бредовенько, но как бы другого выхода не вижу.

Comment: это простая страница без mysql и php

Comment: Приехали... А зачем же в тэгах "php" указали? В таком случае или JS/jQuery использовать, или без вариантов.

Comment: в том и дело... как их использовать??? я 0 и в том и в другом

Comment: Что я могу сказать на это? Есть несколько вариантов: 1) найти того, кто вам это сделает; 2) сесть и поучить самому; 3) найти готовые решения; 4) и, наконец, отказаться от этой идеи.

Comment: @kiberchainik пришлите разметку я постараюсь ответить а лучше залейте её на jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Сохраните как PHP. Посмотрите, как себя ведет:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <header>
        <title>Пример</title>
        <style>
            header,
            footer {
                border: 1px solid #000;
                margin: 1em 0;
                clear: both;
            }

            #leftbloc {
                float: left;
                margin-right: 1em;
                background: #ccc;
                width: 5em;
            }

            #rightbloc {
                float: right;
                margin-right: 1em;
                background: #ccc;
                width: 5em;
            }

            #content {
                margin: <?php echo $_GET['left'] != 'hide' ?  '0 6em' : '0 6em 0 0' ?>;
            }
        </style>
    </header>

    <body>
        <header>
            Шапка
        </header>

        <?php if ($_GET['left'] != 'hide') { ?>
        <section id="leftbloc">
            Левая колонка
        </section>
        <?php } ?>
        <section id="rightbloc">
            Правая колонка
        </section>
        <section id="content">
           <p>Здравствуйте, есть страница, header, leftbloc, content, rightbloc, footer, ну вот я бы хотел сделать возможным скрывать по требованию ЛЕВЫЙ блок (leftbloc) при этом блок контента чтоб асширялся, чтоб не оставалось пустого места

           <ul>
            <li><a href="?left=hide">Без левой колонки</a>
            <li><a href="?left=show">С левой колонкой</a>
           </ul>

        </section>
        <footer>
            Подвал
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное, очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

PHP тут совершенно не причём. Это можно сделать на JS или CSS. 
После того, как вы скроете свой левый блок, то прибавьте его ширину к блоку content и всё.

Comment: я и там и там нуль, помогите пожалуйста